# linux shell script string manipulation with regex

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I search many docs, I am thinking this is possible...

I want to remove (any) duplicated characters from string, using string manipulation, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
var = "aabbcc112233"
var = $(var//(.)\1/1\/g} # this must be wrong...
echo var = $var
```

The result must be:

```
var = abc123
```

I found many examples with sed, etc... Is possible solve this with string manipulation and regex only? not others commands?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

We can use backreferences here:

```
echo "aabbcc112233" | sed 's/\(.\)\1*/\1/g'

abc123
```

The trick here is to match `(.)`, any character, followed optionally by the same character, any number of times, including zero.  Then, we just replace with a single letter.  This effectively will remove all adjacent duplicate letters.

Answer (score 0):

Since regex is just a pattern for string matching, it's not capable to manipulate strings without tools. Unfortunately, shell don't have a built-in to do this, that's why we need `sed` and `awk`.

But due to 'no others commands', I don't think regex is an option. And by 'string manipulation', I suppose you mean shell expansions.

I think there're some ways to do this just using bash built-ins and shell expansions. Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
dup="$1"
# give $dup's first character to $uni
uni=${dup:0:1}

while [ "$dup" ]
do
    # then remove dup's first character
    dup=${dup#?}
    # now if $dup's first NOT equal to $uni's last, append it to $uni
    if [ "${uni: -1:1}" != "${dup:0:1}" ]; then
        uni+=${dup:0:1}
    fi 
done
# we have $uni at last
echo $uni
```

Comment: I have reversed your downvote and would ask that you do the same for me.